# Django how to get request.get_host?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-email

Thankyou for reading my problem.I am not getting the request get host.I am sending an email to the drivers those who registered in my app.I am sending a Booking link with their id in URL. The problem is that i am not getting the host with it. 
For eg

after hitting the link i want him to redirect to the page where he can see the car.

**Output in mail After sending email :**

*Please hit the link and book a car /drivers/2/*

but i want a proper link to send him in mail

**for eg**

*http://127.0.0.1:8000/drivers/1/*

**Views.Py**

```
from django.template import Context, Template as mailt

@csrf_exempt
def rentacar_carapp_approve(request):
    if request.POST:
        try:
            args['driver'] = driver = Driver.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('driver_id'))
            subject = "Please Register Your Car"
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_email = 'bakrshk@gmail.com'
            if to_email is not None:
                template = mailt("""Please hit the link and book a car {{ request.get_host }}{% url 'detail' driver_id=driver_id %}""")
                ctx = Context({'driver_id': driver.id})
                join_message = template.render(ctx)
                send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=[to_email], message=join_message,
                          fail_silently=False)
                print("email sent")
                print(request.get_host)
        except Driver.DoesNotExist:
            print("Driver doesn't exists")
```

**Url.py**

```
url(r'^drivers/(?P<driver_id>\d+)/$', rent_views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Comment: `ctx = Context({'driver_id': driver.id, request: request })`

Comment: Or do `request.get_host()` directly in the view and pass that into the context.

Comment: @BearBrown i done it pass it in the context but still same Please hit the link and book a car /drivers/2/

Comment: @DanielRoseman request.get_host() do i need to have add some library in it .

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i am trying to get the host with it and the driver id .

Comment: What they are saying is that you're forgetting to pass the variables you're using into the context: `{'driver_id': driver_id, 'host': request.get_host()}` so you can then use `{{ host }}` in your template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to build the URL in your view using `build_absolute_uri` method of `HttpRequest`, since this will also add the current protocol (https or http):

```
url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('detail', kwargs={'driver_id': driver.id}))
ctx = Context({'url': url})
template = mailt("""Please hit the link and book a car {{ url }}""")
join_message = template.render(ctx)
```

This should lead to *http://localhost:8000/drivers/2* displayed in your email message.

Comment: Thank You So much . it resolved .  can i ask a question ?

Answer (score -1):

Simply build url like this and try.

```
request.get_host +'/driver/'+driver_id
```

Comment: didnt get this  i will build a url like this but i have to pass driver_id all that

Comment: this isn't a good answer. The problem is `request.get_host` not being rendered. Hard-coding paths in your template is a bad habit and using `{% url %}` template tag is always the preferred approach.